# Issues with Kickstart on Fedora 38

Tags: mount, kickstart, anaconda, dracut, fedora-38

I'm having an issue where I receive the following errors when attempting an install with Anaconda Kickstart. The input below is the default when I enter the ‘inst.ks’ option

Input:

```
setparams 'Install Fedora 38'
    linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=Fedora-S-dvd-\x86_64-38 quiet inst.ks=hd:LABEL=LEXAR:/amd64-kickstart.cfg
    initrdefi /images/pxeboot/inird.img
```

Errors:

```
dracut-initqueue[1610]: Unknown device "/dev//run/install/repo//images/install.img": No such device
dracut-initqueue[1611]: Unknown device "/sys/": No such device

dracut-mount[1860]: mount: /sysroot: special device LiveOS_rootfs does not exist.
dracut-mount[1860]: mount:    dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Then the system just hangs until I hard reset. Any insight into this?